# Dynamic add a multi-dimension array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

The problem is I need to add a multi dimension array dynamically, please look at the following example:

```
var list = [];
var listname;
var height;
var width;

list.push(listname);
list[listname] = height;
list[listname] = width;
```

the code above is not what I expected , which should be  `[listname => [[0]=>height,[1]=>width]]`, what can I do if I do not want to create an array for listname, can I dynamic add a mulit dimension array ? thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, how do you want a multi-dimensional array without wanting to push an array into the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse Arrays with [Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). They are different fundamental data-types<sup>1</sup>

```
var myLists = {};       // name => array
var listname = "stuff"; // why not?
var height = 1;
var width = 2;

// there is no Object.push, but we can assign a property by name
myLists[listName] = [height];
// then we can Array.push into the array we just assigned
myLists[listName].push(width);
```

Then, myLists:

```
{
   stuff: [1, 2]
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>JavaScript *mostly* maintains this distinction - if one doesn't add random properties to Arrays or otherwise fake an Object to behave like an array.

Comment: if later I would like to check whether there is a key inside this object, all I need to do is if (myLists.hasownProperties('stuff'))? thx

Comment: @user782104 `obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)` or `propName in obj` (when *not* as `for(x in y)`) - but they do slightly different things. I prefer the latter (with `in`) for "existence testing" as it will look up the chain, if it ever matters, and it just "looks cleaner" to me. Also, `obj[propname]` is sometimes more appropriate, if the value (and whether or not it is truth-y) if also of importance.

Comment: @user782104 You're welcome. Unless one needs to use an array (i.e. has a sequence of values), I would likely write it like: `myLists[listName] = {width: 2, height: 1}` - it's nicer to give values names (via property names), if appropriate.